# List of Tables doesn't appear

Tags: lists, longtable

I have a problem with List of Tables. It doesn't appear in my document.

The `.cls` file is [HERE](http://exdb.fit.cvut.cz/browser/zp/1213-zima/martiada/FITthesis.cls?rev=1217).

Document:

```
\documentclass[thesis=B,czech]{FITthesis}[2012/06/26]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\department{text}
\title{text}
\authorGN{text}
\authorFN{text}
\authorWithDegrees{text}
\supervisor{text}
\acknowledgements{text}
\abstractCS{text}
\abstractEN{text}
\placeForDeclarationOfAuthenticity{text}
\declarationOfAuthenticityOption{1}
\keywordsCS{text}
\keywordsEN{text}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithout{table}{chapter}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{introduction}
    %
\end{introduction}

\chapter {First}

text

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Function.}
  \label{fig:function}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{ c | c | c }
        $1$ & $2$ & 3 \\ \hline
        \caption{tab}
\label{tab:tab}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\begin{conclusion}
    %
\end{conclusion}

\appendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's because for a List of Tables to appear, you need `\listoftables` somewhere in your document (and compile at least twice on the first go).

Comment: @Werner that's true for standard classes and KOMA, and `memoir` and many others, but not for the class used in the question. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: My suggestion is still true though. There seems very little gain in the automation of `\listoftables` when there are so many other ways of doing it. 13 characters is okay every now and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `FITthesis.cls` **doesn't** require an explicit use of `\listoftables`, since it tries to detect whether the list should be automatically generated or not.

The problem is that the mechanism used to do the automatic detection is not very good, since it's based on the detection of the environment and not on the caption type. If the `table` environment was used in the document, then the LoT will be produced; otherwise, no list is generated.

This is clearly wrong, since one can have tables with captions not associated with the `table` environment (one could have `longtable`, or `threeparttable`, or `\captionof{table}{...}`).

For the list of tables, one finds in `FITthesis.cls`:

```
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\gdef\there@is@a@table{}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@table\label{tab:was:used:in:doc}\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\listoftablescond}{\@ifundefined{r@tab:was:used:in:doc}{}{\listoftables*}}
```

and this means, as I said before, that the LoT will only be generated if `table` was used in the document.

Since in the MWE `table` was not used, the LoT is not produced, even though `longtable` was present. This is clearly a bad design choice that should be corrected by the author/maintainer of the class. If automatic generation is to be done, then the mechanism must be base on the captions, not on specific environments.

One could explicitly invoke `\listoftables` in the document, but the, as soon as `table` is used one will end up having two lists of tables.

The best solution here, while the author/maintainer of the class corrects the issue, is to register also `longtable` for the automatic generation of the LoT, using:

```
\makeatletter
\AtEndEnvironment{longtable}{\gdef\there@is@a@table{}}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[thesis=B,czech]{FITthesis}[2012/06/26]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\AtEndEnvironment{longtable}{\gdef\there@is@a@table{}}
\makeatother

\department{text}
\title{text}
\authorGN{text}
\authorFN{text}
\authorWithDegrees{text}
\supervisor{text}
\acknowledgements{text}
\abstractCS{text}
\abstractEN{text}
\placeForDeclarationOfAuthenticity{text}
\declarationOfAuthenticityOption{1}
\keywordsCS{text}
\keywordsEN{text}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithout{table}{chapter}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
}
\begin{document}


    \begin{longtable}{ c | c | c }
        $1$ & $2$ & 3 \\ \hline
        \caption{tab}
\label{tab:tab}
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]